# Which version of Android sdk contains CameraDevice class

Tags: android

Can any one tell me which version of android sdk contains the class " android.hardware.CameraDevice " .At present i m using android-sdk-windows-1.5_r1. I want to capture image from the web cam. Please help me.

regards,
s.kumaran.

Comment: If one, the latest version does.

Answer (score 3):

CameraDevice is from a pre-1.0 Android API. You should import the `android.hardware.Camera` class instead. See the included API demos too.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Answer (score -2):

It is not an sdk-version who let you use the camera, but just a line in your manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html